# Azure function local setup in PyCharm and publish to Azure

Tags: python, pycharm, azure-functions

I've just switched gears to Azure esp. started working on Azure functions. It's very straightforward to do the deployment using VSCode but I've been unable to find any comprehensive working end-to-end doc/resource about how to set azure function in pycharm, publish it from PyCharm to azure cloud and debug it locally.

I've looked in Microsoft docs but couldn't find anything of value for setting up Azure Func in PyCharm. Could you please suggest if it is possible to do it in PyCharm or do I have to switch to VSCode? (Don't wanna switch just because of Azure Functions though).

PS: If it is possible to set it up in PyCharm, link or details of how-to will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Function is now supported in Rider, WebStorm and IntelliJ and it supports TypeScript, Node, C#, Python and Java. But **PyCharm** most likely be the only JetBrains product that doesn't have a single step setup to **run and debug** Azure Functions.

Currently there is no Azure Function Extension with the help of which functions can be created, debugged and published from **PyCharm**.

If you don't want to switch to VS Code then for now you might like using **IntelliJ** for running, debugging and publishing Azure Functions.

Check this [discussion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40493) to get more information. Also check this [approach](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/4945#issuecomment-783582267) to debug it locally, it can be considered as a workaround but not solution.

Comment: so as a workaround, I should write python code in PyCharm and use IntelliJ for running, debugging and publishing Azure Functions?

Comment: You can even develop python script in IntelliJ by downloading and installing Python and configuring at least one Python SDK. Check this [document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-python-sdk.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Pycharm does not integrate directly Azure Functions.
I've set up a DevOps Pipeline in my function, so everytime I need to run and test it I push my code from Pycharm on a dedicated branch and the function is deployed on Azure.